# Add markup to all links inside DIV

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink

Is it possible at all to target all links inside of a DIV and have it open up in a new window?

```
<div class="related-info"> <-- Target any link inside of "related-info"
       <a href="http://#">Link</a>  <-- Add in target="_blank"
    <div class="another-div">
       <a href="http://#">Link</a>  <-- Add in target="_blank"
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
$('.related-info a').attr('target', '_blank')
```

- [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector)
- [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr)

Comment: Assuming this is the only thing with that class, or that everything with that class is to be affected.

Comment: @ScottHunter I think *target all links inside of a DIV* wants the same

Comment: "Assuming this is the only thing with that class"

Answer (score 2):

Yes, possible. Use this:

```
$(".related-info, .another-div").find("a").attr("target", "_blank");
```